# Timezone tests in testcafe

Tags: typescript, date, testing, timezone, testcafe

I've got one quick question. Basically I want to be able to run testcafe test cases on a web application for different time zones in JavaScript without using any external libraries or packages. What is the best way to change the browser time zone dynamically so I can test datepickers for example?

I've tried some approaches by using code from below:

```
function changeTimezone(date, ianatz) {

var invdate = new Date(date.toLocaleString('en-US', {
timeZone: ianatz
}));

var diff = date.getTime() - invdate.getTime();

const tmz = new Date(date.getTime() - diff);
Date = function(){return tmz;}
return tmz;
}


const setTimeZones = () => {
 const myDate = new Date();
 var newDate = changeTimezone(myDate, "Pacific/Fiji");
};
```

When I run the previous example it's not changing dates in my browser when selecting datepickers. I've tried few more approaches but it didn't work. I want to mention that I don't want to change date on my machine but simulate sensors like behavior that we have in dev tools. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TestCafe does not have API to change browser time zones. However, if you want to simulate time zones as in DevTools you can use a workaround.
The test code:

```
fixture `f`
    .beforeEach(async t => {
        const browserConnection = t.testRun.browserConnection;
        const providerPlugin    = browserConnection.provider.plugin;
        const browserClient     = providerPlugin._getBrowserProtocolClient(providerPlugin.openedBrowsers[browserConnection.id]);
        const cdpClient         = await browserClient.getActiveClient();

        await cdpClient.Emulation.setTimezoneOverride({ timezoneId: 'Pacific/Fiji' });
    });
 
test('Check', async t => {
    await t.navigateTo('http://127.0.0.1:8081');

    await t.debug();
});
```

The html page:

```
<body>
    <div id="target"></div>
    <script>
        const div = document.querySelector('#target');

        div.innerHTML = (new Date()).toString();
    </script>
</body>
```

Please note that the workaround uses internal API, which can be changed in the future, so you should use it carefully.